# Rails Log In Form HTML?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I have set up a 'blog' website with secure log-in and sign-up functionality. My question is where does rails hide the html mark-up for these as I want to add some styling? I don't want to style the comments form though, if they are the same source mark-up. I have checked all the 'view's and cannot find the code for the log-in/out form?
[image]

Comment: What plugin do you use for login?

Comment: @Jakub I used the Devise plug in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise is a Rails engine - which means that it stores all its controllers and views in the Gem bundle. However devise has a generator that will copy its views so that you can modify them:

```
$ rails generate devise:views
```

Comment: That's brilliant - is there anything else I need to be aware of before I start editing my forms with CSS? Also I would like to add extra fields to my sign up-form (name, nationality etc) - will this break my website?

Comment: No that should be fine provided that you do the correct migration and don't forget about `attr_accessible`.

Comment: how do you mean the 'correct' migration and what is the attr_accessible - how do I do this bit?

Comment: By correct I simply meant to not forget to add the fields to the correct model. `attr_accessible` is a bit out of scope for a comment, try googling around, it's quite widely documented - see for instance here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the CSS for your website. That will not alter the HTML of the login form, but the form is already optimized as it is (inputs, buttons & links).

If you do not want to edit other forms, you should look at the source code of that login form. It will probably has some unique ID or class you can use for styling.

Comment: No they don't, I have been looking for them!